# In line 11 how do i make it so that i don't need to use so many spaces

Tags: java

how do I remove all the spaces without changing the format and what is the best option to do so and if so would I be using the System.out.printf(); or some other directive. please respond with java and not C++. I would really appreciate anyone who helps and will gladly thank them for helping me with my own problems.

```
public class WorldPopulation{
    //main string
    public static void main(String[] args) {
             //prints title 
            System.out.println(" This is a estimate of world population growth within 300 year time span. ");
            //prints number value
            System.out.println("                       Numbers are in millions");
            //number of rows and columns
            final int ROWS = 6;
            final int COLUMNS = 7;

            //population numbers array
            int [] [] populations =
                {
                        {106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766},
                        {502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268},
                        {2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46},
                        {163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628},
                        {2, 7, 26, 82, 172, 307, 392},
                        {16, 24, 3, 74, 167, 511, 809}
                };
            //continents array
            String[] continents =
                {
                        "Africa",
                        "Asia",
                        "Australia",
                        "Europe",
                        "North America",
                        "South America"
                };
            //prints the years used in the estimation       
            System.out.println("                Year 1750 1800 1850 1900 1950 2000 2050");

            //print population data
            for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {          
             //print i'th row       
            System.out.printf("%20s", continents[i]);
            //prints the columns and the rows
            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {

                System.out.printf("%5d", populations [i] [j]);
            }
                System.out.println(); //start new line at end of row
        }



            //print column totals
            System.out.printf("%20s","World total");
            //prints the total estimated population in the years used
            for (int  j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
            {
                int total = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                    total = total + populations[i][j];
                }
                //format of the printed totals  
                System.out.printf("%5d", total);

            }
            //starts new line after each row
            System.out.println();
        }
        //end of class and program.
    }
```

Comment: you should try to reduce the code in this question to the lines you need help with. And change the title of the question. There are no experts on "line 11", but there are people who know a lot about formatting output.

Comment: Line 11 is a blank line.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the "Numbers are in millions" line, you could try adding tabs instead: System.out.println("\t\t\tNumbers are in millions");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
System.out.format("%15s%s", "", "Test");
```

There you have a string of length 15 followed by a string of undefined. Because the first string being formatted is an empty string, you will have 15 spaces printed instead.